# Linear Transformation Involving Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$ \phi : P2 → P3, \phi(p)(t) = tp(t) + p'(t) $

I am to decide whether this is a linear transformation or not. I am having difficulty understanding what the transformation is actually doing. I.e. (p) is a polynomial of degree 2 and t is?

Comment: $t$ is the variable in the polynomial.  For instance, $p$ might be $t^2-3$ or something.  Then $\phi(p)$ would be $t(t^2-3) + 2t$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why it wasn't denoted $\phi (p(t)) = ... $ ?

Comment: @Sofia because $p$ is the polynomial, not $t$. $p(t)$ is the polynomial ***evaluated*** at $t$, not the polynomial which is a function.

Answer (score 1):

I would write $\varphi: \Bbb P^2 \to \Bbb P^3$, $\varphi(p):t \mapsto tp(t) + p'(t)$. For example, $\varphi$ maps the polynomial $t^2+1$ to $t(t^2+1)+(t^2+1)' = t^3+3t$.

Let $p,q \in \Bbb P^2$. Then, $\varphi(p+q)(t) = t(p+q)(t) + (p+q)'(t) = t[p(t)+q(t)] + p'(t) + q'(t) = [tp(t)+p'(t)] + [tq(t) + q'(t)] = \varphi(p)(t) + \varphi(q)(t) = (\varphi(p)+\varphi(q))(t)$.

I'll leave the multiplicative part to you.